# Why in OpenGL my camera rotates 180 degrees every other time?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to do something like a 3d-shooter.
The calculations seems to be correct, but it is works every other time with a spread with 180 degree rotation on every call glutPostRedisplay(). I understood that thanks to that red line.
I do this with such IDE: Code Blocks / Qt Creator under Linux(Ubuntu x64).

main.cpp

```
#include "Functions.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(wnd_width, wnd_height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 100);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL my");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    glutSpecialFunc(KeyPressed);
    GLdouble aspect = wnd_width/wnd_height;
    gluPerspective(90, aspect, 0.1, 10);
    glTranslatef(0, -0.3, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Functions.h

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int wnd_width=1300;
int wnd_height=900;
float pos_x=0, pos_z=0.1;
float angle = 0;
float speed = 0.1;

void DrawFloor(){
    glVertex3d(1, 0, 2.5);
    glVertex3d(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3d(-1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3d(-1, 0, 2.5);
}

void DrawWall(float x, float width, float height){
    glVertex3f(x, height, 0);
    glVertex3f(x, height, width);
    glVertex3f(x, 0, width);
    glVertex3f(x, 0, 0);
}

void DrawLine(){
    glVertex3f(0, 0.1, -1);
    glVertex3f(0, 0.1, 1);
}

void KeyPressed(int key, int x, int y){
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: {
        //pos_x = speed * cos(3.14*angle/180);
        //pos_z = speed * sin(3.14*angle/180);
        pos_z+=0.1;
        break;
    }
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: {
        pos_x = speed*cos(angle);
        pos_z = speed*sin(angle);
        break;
    }
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: {
        angle += 1;
        pos_x = speed * cos(3.14 * angle/180);
        pos_z = speed * sin(3.14 * angle/180);
        break;
    }
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: {
        angle -= 3;
        pos_x = speed * cos(3.14 * angle/180);
        pos_z = speed * sin(3.14 * angle/180);
        break;
    }
    }
    std::cout<<"x: "<<pos_x<<'\t';
    std::cout<<"z: "<<pos_z<<'\n';
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(){
    glClearColor(0.6, 0.8, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gluLookAt(pos_x, 0, pos_z, pos_x, 0, pos_z+0.2, 0, 1, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.7);
    DrawFloor();
    glColor3f(0, 0.8, 0.1);
    DrawWall(-0.5, 2, 0.7);
    DrawWall(0.5, 2, 0.7);
    glEnd();

    glLineWidth(2);
    glColor3f(0.7, 0.2, 0.2);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    DrawLine();
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Idle(){
    //pos_z+=0.01;
    //glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: isn't `pos_x = ???` should reference old position? like `pos.x = pos.x + speed.x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the fixed function stack, so you'll have to learn what `glMatrixMode` does and how transformation matrices are managed in those old ways.

Anyway, consider this a possible implementation of `glMatrixMode`

```
void glMatrixMode(GLenum m)
{
    switch(m){
    case GL_MODELVIEW:  ctx->M = &ctx->matrix_modelview;  break;
    case GL_PROJECTION: ctx->M = &ctx->matrix_projection; break;
    case GL_TEXTURE:    ctx->M = &ctx->matrix_texture;    break;
    case GL_COLOR:      ctx->M = &ctx->matrix_color;      break;
    }
}
```

On other words, there's a (context) global matrix selected with `glMatrixMode`, that's subsequently used for all folloing matrix manipulations.

*Hence, `glMatrixMode` is **not** some form of initialization, but something you use to switch (often several times) during rendering a frame!* Your use of it in the `main` function is kind of pointless. You must use it in your drawing function.

Furthermore, every matrix manipulation multiplies on top, of what's currently in `ctx->M`. `gluLookAt` is normally used with a identity matrix. If you don't reset you identity, that `gluLookAt` will work relative to the look-at done previously. So what you want is this:

```
void display(){
    glClearColor(0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.); /* <<<----* */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTIOM);
    glLoadIdentity();
    setup_projection_here();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(pos_x, 0, pos_z, pos_x, 0, pos_z+0.2, 0, 1, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    /* ... */

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

(*) Also you normally want to clear to `alpha = 1` on the main framebuffer, unless you're planning on drawing window-translucent imagery. With `alpha = 0` things might look correct in the window, but if a screenshot is taken, or some screen recording or sharing is used, it may cause undesired transparence.